# Не прописывается книга при вызове процедуры

Tags: access, delphi-7

При вызове этой процедуры в DBGrid должна прописываться книга. Но этого не происходит в форме. Но в базу значения прописываются. Помогите вычислить ошибку в коде. Кнопка, по которой происходит запись:

```
procedure TForm28.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
try
Form29.ADOQuery1.Edit;
ADOTable1.FieldByName('КодЧитателя').AsString:=
Form29.ADOQuery1.FieldByName('КодЧитателя').AsString;
ADOTable1.Post;
Form27.ADOQuery1.Edit;
Form27.ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Количество').AsInteger:=
Form27.ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Количество').AsInteger - 1;
Form27.ADOQuery1.Post;
except
MessageDlg('Заполните все поля', mtCustom, [mbOK], 0);
end;
Form29.ADOQuery2.Requery;
Edit1.Clear;
try
ADOTable1.Insert;
except
end;
DBDateTime.Text:=DateToStr(SysUtils.Date);
end;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: скорее всего что нижний датасет нужно обновить. А после закрытия и открытия программы данные появляются?

Answer (score 1):

Последней строкой в процедуре выполняйте `ADOTable1.Refresh`.